Using results of log-log regression for forecasting
If I have a regression in with logs taken of both sides to give the equation:
$ln(y) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 ln(x)$
and need to calculate the expected change in $y$ for a given $x$. I can see from reading various sources that using differentiation you can show that $\beta_1$ is the elasticity. So an $z$% change in $x$ should result in an $z*\beta_1$% change in $y$.
However, why is the following method not a correct way of calculating the impact on y of a % change in $x$?
Taking exponents to make y the subject of the formula: $$ y = e^{\beta_0}x^{\beta_1} $$
The value of y in period t is calculated as: $$ y_t = e^{\beta_0}x_t^{\beta_1} $$
To calculate percentage change in y between periods t-1 and t, divide by $y_{t-1}$: $$\frac {y_t}{y_{t-1}} = \frac{e^{\beta_0} x_t^{\beta_1}}{y_{t-1}}$$
Substitute for $y_{t-1}$: $$
\frac {y_t}{y_{t-1}} = \frac{e^{\beta_0}  x_t^{\beta_1}}{e^{\beta_0}x_{t-1}^{\beta_1}}
$$
Cancel out $e^{\beta_0}$: $$\frac {y_t}{y_{t-1}} = \frac{x_t^{\beta_1}}{x_{t-1}^{\beta_1}}$$
Apply the quotient rule: $$\frac {y_t}{y_{t-1}} = (\frac{x_t}{x_{t-1}})^{\beta_1}$$
And thus an $z$% increase in x leads to a $((1+z)^{\beta_1}-1)$% increase in y.
This would produce different results to using $\beta_1$ as the elasticity to calculate changes in y in response to changes in x, so both cannot be correct.
I'm sure I must be missing something here but this is not my speciality.

You are correct.  But your final formula is infinitesimally equivalent to a $\beta_1z\times 100$% increase, so the distinction is exactly like that between an instantaneous interest rate and compounded interest.  These are fundamental properties of logs and exponentials.  I believe the standard economic definition of elasticity is the infinitesimal (instantaneous) version.  (BTW, note the distinction between a multiplier and a percent: the latter is $100$ times the multiplier.)

Thanks @whuber To check I've understood correctly, does this mean that  $y_t = y_{t-1}(\frac{x_t}{x_{t-1}})^{\beta_1}$ would be correct whereas, taking $\beta_1$ as the elasticity, $y_t = y_{t-1}(1+((\frac{x_t}{x_{t-1}}-1)*\beta_1))$ would only be true for an infinitesimal change in $x$?

Writing $x_t/x_{t-1}=1+z$ and supposing $|z|\lt 1,$ the Binomial Theorem implies $$(1+z)^\beta=1+\beta z + O(z^2).$$  Thus, when $z^2$ is small enough to ignore, the result follows.  When $z^2$ cannot be ignored (but still $|z|\lt 1$), you can continue the expansion as $$(1+z)^\beta = 1+\beta z + \frac{\beta(\beta-1)}{2!}z^2 + \cdots + \frac{\Gamma(\beta+1)}{n!\Gamma(\beta+1-n)}z^n+\cdots$$
